# Ubuntu 15.10 crashes with kernel 4.3

Tags: kernel, compiz, crash, 15.10

I'm buying a new Skylake CPU and motherboard and I read that to get proper support for Skylake, I need Linux kernel 4.3. I tried installing it from the .deb packages in http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-wily/ . Installation worked and I got to the login screen with the new kernel without problems. However, when I tried to login, Ubuntu immediately crashed, showing briefly some colourful mess on the screen and then threw me back to the login screen. I tried several times and always the same result.

Sadly I didn't keep the dmesg log from that session and I don't want to try installing the new kernel again because it took me some time to recover from it (somehow the crash completely messed my Unity configuration and I had to delete my ~/.config/dconf folder to get into working state again even with the old kernel). From what I was able to gather from dmesg, however, was that compiz somehow crashed with segfault.

I understand I'm not giving all the information that might be needed to solve the problem (like the dmesg log), but I would like to know if there are known issues/bugs discussed elsewhere that could be related to this? Just about anything to get me started on troubleshooting.

I'm using NVidia proprietary drivers version 352.42 from the Ubuntu repository. This might be related since the crash seemed to be some kind of display related failure (either drivers, kernel, compiz or some combination of them).

Comment: Probably the driver did not build for the new kernel. You need to install it from terminal and see if it is built or not.

Comment: On the first attempt, I did get an error of of the nvidia driver not building correctly. From the error, I deduced that this had something to do with virtualbox. I just removed virtualbox since I rarely use it anyway and installed the kernel again without any errors. Then this happened.

Comment: Remove the nvidia driver.

Comment: I kind of need it to play games. Games are the reason why I'm upgrading my computer in the first place :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working with Intel Skylake Developer platform kit with the 4.2 kernel for a while and the 4.2 kernel should be sufficient for you current needs.  Is there any specific reason you believe 4.3 is more appropriate for your system?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I indeed ended up using the stock 4.2 kernel from Ubuntu repository and everything has been working fine. I was under impression that Skylake support in 4.2 was somehow incomplete, but this turned out to be not true.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the understanding that kernel 4.2.x series could run the Skylake (using a Skylake laptop right now) but not all features are enabled.  It was apparently a bit of a hack to get the Intel drivers to work (HD520), complete native support is in 4.3 +, which should be available in a few months with 16.04.  That all being said, STEAM work on this new laptop with kernel 4.2.